# Wordpress nav-menu crashes?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I have really serious problem with my WordPress site. It has a very large navigation primary menu (about 12 main items and every item has really big depth).

First thing I did was to extend max_input_vars so my phpinfo() give me this:

```
Directive   Local Value Master Value
max_input_vars  5000    1000
memory_limit    512M    96M
```

But, even I did that I have really serious error with WordPress menu: sometimes, even with no reason my menu crashes. I go to the site and in nav menu line I had only two items "HOME" and configure.

When I go to appearances->menus half of my menu items just disappear with no reason. Can somebody tell me can this be happen because of fact that two persons modifying site from same account (maybe even same pages or posts on site ) so there is no something like synchronisation of input and for result there is a collision in database?

Or that problem can be addressed to not enough input vars (but now it's 5000)?

Comment: What do you mean the menu "crashes"?

Comment: Crashes means-dissapear ..only left home and configure item... configure is linked to appearances->menus , and when i get there half of items dissapeared,and checkboxes that were cheked now are all uncheked ...